# Is this program to find prime numbers wrong?

Tags: primes, algol

While reading “Code: The Hidden Language of Computer,” I came across the ALGOL program that the author included to find the prime numbers through 10,000 using the Sieve algorithm. Below is the code.

```
begin
   Boolean array a[2:10000];
   integer i, j;

   for i :=2 step 1 until 10000 do
       a[i] :=true;

   for i :=2 step 1 until 100 do
       if a[i] then 
            for j := 2 step 1 until 10000 / i do
                a[i*j] :=false;
   for i :=2 step 1 until 10000 do
       if a[i] then
           print(i);
end
```

When I usually see a program I test it by using real values to see its validity. In this case, the concern I have is with the line `For j:=....`. If we take `i` as 3 and 3 as the specific point in the steps of `j`. Then `j` would be 1. So, `a[i*j]`, i.e., `a[3]`, would be false when it should be true since its a prime. Can `j` or `i` be equal to 1?

Am I missing something over here? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What happened when you ran it?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I didn't really run it. I will do so now.

Comment: `for j := 2` - what do you think the 2 means?

Comment: That's why `j` starts at 2 !

Comment: @Mat But, its then divided by i. So, 3/3=1 or 4/4=1,...

Comment: No, it is not divided by `i`.

Comment: j := 2 step 1 until 10000 $\div$ i. Can you please explain further?

Comment: The division is only for 10000. You might rephrase the loop: limit = 10000/i ; for j := 2 step 1 until limit do ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for j := 2
         ^
```

`j` starts at 2, so only non-prime numbers' indexes (i*2, i*3, ...) would be set to `false` in the array.

Comment: But, its divided by i.

Comment: Only the upper bound is divided by i. This is done so that j starts at 2, but i*j <= 10000.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by upper bound.

Comment: In the for-loop, there are two bounds for a loop-variable: lower and upper. And the variable goes through all values from lower bound to upper. In your case, the loop-variable (j) goes from the lower bound (**2**) to upper bound (**10000/i**) with the step of 1, so j = 2, 3, 4, ... , integer-part-of (10000/i).

Comment: Ohhh, wait a second: Its not (2 step 1 until 10000) / i , but 2 step 1 until (10000 / i ). Silly me :P

Comment: Just out of curiosity how would one make the distinction between the two more clearer. For example, what if I wanted to represent the former. How would that go? Would simple parenthesis suffice, or braces?

Comment: The for loop has its syntax, something like: for <variable> := <expression> step <expression> until <expression> do <statement>. An expression can contain division, but there is no way to apply a division to the whole construction. Of course you can write: for j := 2 / i step 1 until 10000 / i. (Not sure if you want to divide step as well.), or just use `j / i` inside the loop everywhere instead of j. But you cannot 'divide' the whole for-loop.

Comment: @user29568 you've been here another of countless victims of the principle **"omitting parentheses is evil"**. For people in the know the superfluous parentheses seem sooo unnecessary. It's sooo *"cool"* to drop as many parentheses as one possibly can, it becomes our second nature. The problem is, not only compilers read code. People do too. :) with time you'll be dropping parentheses too. :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested here is a slightly faster implementation of this algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
long long sumPrime(long long n){
   
    vector<long long> isPrime(n+1,true);
    for (long long i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        if(isPrime[i]){
            cout<<i<<" ";
        }
        for (long long j = i*i; j <= n; j=j+i) {
            isPrime[j]=false;
        }
    }
    
}



int main() {
    cout<<sumPrime(2000000);
    return 0;
}
```